# Are Yamato/Tenzo their actual names, or only code names?

Tags: naruto

I'm thinking that a certain category of Anbu black ops takes children at birth and trains them in codes, deception and subterfuge so thoroughly that they actually don't name the kids and they just grow up with their identities constantly being changed.

My theory is that Captain Yamato/Tenzo doesn't have one. And neither would Sai if my theory works.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sai and Yamato are code names. In the anime and I believe manga as well, we even watch both of them get assigned those names by Danzo and Tsunade respectively at around the same time right before they go to meet Naruto for the first time.

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sai

> Sai was orphaned as a child and recruited into Root, a secret branch of the Anbu under the leadership of Danzō Shimura. There, he was raised and conditioned to have no personality, personal connections, or a name; "Sai" being given to him for the purposes of joining Team Kakashi.

and 3 snippets from http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yamato

> He was soon afterwards found by Danzō Shimura. Having lost all memory of who he was, the boy was taken in by Danzō, where he was recruited into the Anbu's Root division under the codename Kinoe (甲, Kinoe)........Later, Kinoe was re-assigned to Team Ro under Kakashi's command. Joining his new squad, Kinoe was given a warm welcome to his new allies and insisted by Kakashi that he go by his chosen name of "Tenzō", which he happily agreed to......... "Yamato" and "Tenzō" are actually codenames given to him, reflecting his time as Team Kakashi's captain and an Anbu member, respectively; his real name is unknown.